# Automate preinstalled Add-On action (3D-Print Toolbox)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, 3d-printing, stl

I've been using the 3D Print Toolbox Add-on in Blender to check for and fix non manifold edges and would like to automate the actions on a list of STL files. Right now I do the following:

1. Import an STL into Blender
2. Select the object
3. Open the 3D Print Toolbox
4. Use add on action under **3D-Print > Checks > Solid** to check if the model has any non manifold edges
5. If there are non manifold edges, click **3D-Print > Clean Up > Make Manifold** to repair the object
6. Blender then freezes while importing, checking, repairing, and exporting the file without a progress indicator or notification of success/failure which leads to a lot of manual checking if Blender has finished and "unfrozen" :(

Actions I perform are all the same in every case and I have a filepath for every STL I process. I looked at the 3D-Print addon code and have some programming knowledge but haven't found any resources on automating addon actions in Blender.

What would be the best way for me to automate this check and repair of STLs? Thanks!

Comment: You could use python and connect it to the 3D ToolBox, but unless you are going to find the same issue with the STL's your using there's really no way to do that...at-least at the moment (to many variables - overlapping geometry, missing faces, inverted faces etc... ).

Comment: @RickT Yes, using python to connect to the 3D ToolBox addon is what I would like to do. Most of my STLs have the same issues that 3D ToolBox is able to fix. Is there a reference you can point me to for connecting to addons?

Comment: you may want to contact one of the developers.  https://github.com/agapas/3d-print-toolbox-modified